# How to make an alert when a wrong value is filled into a cell EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to make an alert when a cell has a value that does not match that of a neighbor cell in a different column in Excel.

For instance, a value "Complete" can be filled in to the cells of column A only when the neighbor cell of column B has a value "Available".

So I want an alert to pop up when "Complete" is filled into a cell of column A but the cell of column B does not have a value"Available".

Can someone please share me idea of doing this? useful links / sample VBA codes etc..?

Comment: You do not need VBA for this. You may use Datavalidation with the help of a "Helper Cells" to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the below code, import it on worksheet change event and try:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then '<- If column A change
        If Target.Value = "Complete" And Target.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "Available" Then
            MsgBox "Please review records."
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```